# ansible mysql_user - not granting privileges

Tags: ansible

I have a task configured as:

```
 - name: Create DB User
      mysql_user:
        name: dbuser
        host: "{{ item }}"
        password: "{{ mysql_db_password }}"
        priv: "someDB.*:ALL"
      with_items:
        - "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
        - 127.0.0.1
        - ::1
        - localhost
```

This creates the user entry just fine, but 2 things.
1) I can not connect to the DB via that user
2) I assume I have the priv: line correct to apply all privileges, but when I compare in the DB user table I see that actually none of the privileges have been granted.

Not sure what I have done wrong here, guidance appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain that when you are connecting to the database your origin is one of the values you're using for `host`?

Comment: I am trying on the db host and it is using localhost so yes. Certain.

Comment: i tried your code and it worked fine for me (meaning i could login to the DB), `priv` value looks OK. One remark i have is that the `host` is probably meant to be always `localhost` (?). Documentation says it should be: `the 'host' part of the MySQL username`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with this block. It was me missing the fact that I had the wrong password referenced in a j2 template file.